# Where does okular store annotations in Debian wheezy?

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, okular

In Ubuntu, it was in `.kde/share/apps/okular/docdata`, which a copy solved everything.

But in Debian wheezy it doesn't work, and I can't find where they are stored.

Comment: I'm not sure, but `~/.kde4/`, `~/.local/share/` and `~/.config/` are good starting places to search. It might be that KDE4 uses Akonadi (a MySQL database) instead, though.